# Python get and set methods versus @property decorator

Tags: python, properties, python-decorators, getter-setter

I am exploring decorators in Python, and as a person who came to Python from other languages, I am a bit confused about the purpose of `@property` and its `@xxx.setter` brother. In Java and C++ `get_xxx()` and `set_xxx()` are usually the way to organize encapsulation. In Python we have these two decorators, which require specific syntax, and name matching in order to work. How is `@property` better than `get-set` methods?

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749087/python-properties-vs-combined-set-get-method) and still, what are the advantages of `@property` besides the availability of the `+=` operator?

Comment: The point is **you shouldn't write getters and setters in Python**. This is *the key thing to understand*. Just use normal `self.x = whatever`.

Comment: The *advantage* of using `property` is that you **dont' have to write boilerplate getters and setters**. You just use plain attributes, and *if and when* you require controlling access to the attribute, **only then** do you add a property, and you don't break the interface for clients to your class, or your own implementation. So you get *encapsulation without boilerplate getters and setters*

Comment: See [this answer to a related question I wrote a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266014/5014455)

Comment: "which require specific syntax, and name matching in order to work." They don't actually, although, it will if you use the `@` syntax, but that isn't required.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, the link to your answer provided me with all the info I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best part of using `property` for an attribute is that *you don't need it*.

The philosophy in Python is that classes attributes and methods are all public, but by convention - when you prefix their name with a single "_"

The mechanism behing "property", the descriptor protocol, allows one to change a previous dumb plain attribute into an instrumented attribute, guarded with code for the getter and setter, if the system evolves to a situation where it is needed.

But by default, a `name` attribute in a class, is just a plain attribute. You do `person.name = "Name"`- no guards needed, no setting method needed nor recommended.  When and if it one needs a guard for that (say, to capitalize the name, or filter on improper words), whatever code uses that attribute needs no change: with the use of property, attribute assignment still takes place with the "=" operator.

Other than that, if using "=" does not look prettier than  `person.set_name("Name")` for you, I think it does for most people. Of course, that is subjective.